# Spring boot Query validation

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Works on PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT T FROM TAG T WHERE T.NAME = 'RAYYAN'
```

Throws `IllegalArgumentException` in my Java code

[image: ERROR IN PICTURE]

> Reason: Validation failed for query for method

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Tag T WHERE t.name = :tags")
public Tag findByName(@Param("tags") String tagString);
```

I have a Maven Spring boot project.

It contains entities, repositories, service interface, and serviceImplementation class(es).

Entities are db-connected, repos are used to make query methods to gain data from database. Service interface and its implementation is an added layer so that services on the project is done.

Now, the query in my repository is fine on the pgAdmin, but from within Java, it throws IllegalArgumentException, Validation failed for query for method.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, your param name in query and method have to be same, so change the method parameter from tagString to tags.

Comment: No, so when I have defined the ("tags") in the paranthesis and quotations, it should have worked.